# Flutter transform MIME format in UI

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, mime, mime-message

I have a working on a project that requires me to load a file in MIME format and render it on the mobile app. I have sucessfully load the string out from the file but I failed to render it on the UI. The following is the sample code that I used to load the string. However, there is a limitation on the below code which it cannot load MIME file with attachment inside. So, hopofully someone might be able to help me solve the aboe 2 problems.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


await rootBundle.loadString("lib/resources/images/hihi.txt")
```